# Free dependency graph of visual studio C# project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, graph, dependencies, free

I'm looking to map the C# classes of my Visual Studio 2019 project on a dependency graph.
I've seen some tools available but they require you to pay for a full version (ReSharper, NDepend).
I'm looking for something free/cheap. If anyone has ideas, please let me know.

Comment: You can still use the NDepend graph for free during 14 days with the full-featured trial version and ask for trial extension https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph

Answer (score 20):

I have recently made a dotnet tool for this if you're interested.

## Try [DependenSee](https://github.com/madushans/dependensee)

It doesn't integrate with VS, but you can visualize the dependencies in an html file (also support XML, JSON and writing out results to console.)

to install

- <strike>Make sure you have dotnet 5 runtime installed</strike>
- **Make sure you have dotnet 6 runtime installed**
- run `dotnet tool install dependensee --global`
- once installed, run `dependensee "path/to/root/of/csproj/files" "path/to/output.html"`
- By default it doesn't include nuget packages, but can be enabled with `-P` switch
- to see all options, run `dependensee` with no args.

HTML output looks like this

[image: DependenSee Graph]

## For Continuous Integration Scenarios

There are command line options allowing you to output XML or JSON for further processing, either writing them to a file or writing to Standard Output allowing to pipe the output to other command line tools without touching the filesystem if necessary.

Comment: does it support .net 4.5 projects ?

Comment: Currently no, since the csproj format is a bit different. (may pick up nuget packages). Can look into adding support.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only goes one level. It works *at all*, which puts it a step above a lot of other tools that also claim to do this, but the output isn't very useful as a dependency diagram/graph/tree, as a flat packages.config shows exactly as much information.

Comment: packages.config shows nuget packages I think. This tool shows the references between projects (and optionally nuget packages they reference). So you can have say 3 projects that reference each other and each have nuget packages, then packages.config will only show those nuget packages not references between .csproj files?

Comment: Happy to report as of today (v1.2.1) .NET Framework projects are supported. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DependenSee/

Comment: Does it work with `*.sln` files or just with `*.csproj` files?

Comment: latest version currently looks for csproj and vbproj files. Does not inspect sln files.

Comment: The image shows exactly what I'm looking for. Tried the tool. Could not build it from source, (for me) unclear how to use it Also could not use it from the Nuget package. I feel like a dummy and I can't find the 'DependenSee for dummies' guide. :-(

Comment: try the instructions in this answer. You don't have to build the tool (acquire via `dotnet tool install ...` ), or your project. (tool reads csproj files). More info available in the [readme here](https://github.com/madushans/dependensee?tab=readme-ov-file#dependensee) as well.